# Эмуляция <INPUT PLACEHOLDER> для <DIV CONTENTEDITABLE> на любой технологии HTML/CSS/JS? [РЕШЕНО]

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue3

Пытаюсь сэмулировать заполнитель `<input placeholder="...">` для `<div contenteditable>`.

Первое что приходит в голову: добавить `::before` и после фокуса на редактируемом элементе `<div ...>` удалить содержащий его класс.

**Проблема**: Попробуйте запустить код и кликнуть на текст "Отредактируйте поле ...", как это делается с обычным `<input type=text>` - С фокусом все нормально, но текстовый курсор теряется. Предполагаю потому что клик был на `::before`. Если же кликнуть в свободном месте(правее), все работает как ожидается - `placeholder` пропадает и курсор оказывается в поле, после чего можно сразу печатать.

**Вопрос**: Как достичь желаемого эффекта? Конечно без всяких дополнительных слоев. Может есть какой JS/API/CSS, позволяющий делать элемент `::before` не перекрывающим своего родителя?

РЕШЕНО: Первым же комментарием от @Grundy CSS pointer-events: none;

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const comp = {
  setup() {
    const showPh = ref(true)
    return {
      showPh
    }
  },
  template: `
   <div
      v-bind:class="['edit', {['edit-ph']: showPh}]"
      contenteditable="true"
      @focus="() => {showPh = false}"
      @blur="({target}) => {target.textContent = '';showPh = true}"
   ></div>

   <p>Для сброса надо кликнуть в любом месте.</p>`
}

createApp(comp).mount('#app')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.edit {
  border: solid 1px rgb(182, 182, 182);
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.edit-ph::before {
  position: relative;
  content: 'Отредактируйте поле ...';
  color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
  cursor: text;
  /* РЕШЕНИЕ */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: @Grundy Да, работает! Как все оказалось просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно выставить [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events): `none` у псевдо элемента, тогда клик по нему будет проигнорирован

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const comp = {
  setup() {
    const showPh = ref(true)
    return {
      showPh
    }
  },
  template: `
   <div
      v-bind:class="['edit', {['edit-ph']: showPh}]"
      contenteditable="true"
      @focus="() => {showPh = false}"
      @blur="({target}) => {target.textContent = '';showPh = true}"
   ></div>

   <p>Для сброса надо кликнуть в любом месте.</p>`
}

createApp(comp).mount('#app')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.edit {
  border: solid 1px rgb(182, 182, 182);
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.edit-ph::before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  content: 'Отредактируйте поле ...';
  color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Супер. Отлично работает. Я чувствовал, что есть какое-то свойство, но не мог понять куда копать, зациклился на JS.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, как альтернативу можно было попробовать отлавливать click по диву и выставлять фокус

Comment: _отлавливать click по диву(с)_ - Это не работает, чего я только там не пробовал, даже с задержкой по времени, после явного удаления класса. В том то и дело что элемент в фокусе, а курсор исчезает вместе с `::before`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, да, как-то неочевидно и руками предлагают не focus вызывать а selection